# Increasing Eigenvalue in $V_t = \lambda I + \sum_{s=1}^{t} A_s A_{s}^T$ as $t$ increases

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, conic-sections

I am reading a paper on bandits where it defines a matrix:

$$V_t = \lambda I + \sum_{s=1}^{t} A_{s} A_{s}^{T} $$

where $\lambda$ is a scalar constant, $I \in R^{d \times  d}$, $A_s \in R^{d}$

Basically we have a sequence of vectors $(A_s)_{s=1}^{\infty}$ and as time goes we keep adding the outerproducts of those vectors with the matrix $V_t$.

The paper says that as $t$ increases the eigenvalues of the matrix $V_t$ increases.

I am not sure why this is the case. Could anyone help me with the intuition behind this claim? Also where should I begin to try to prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your matrices are positive semi-definite and selfadjoint (hermitian). Given a selfadjoint matrix $A$, denote by $\lambda_1(A),\ldots,\lambda_n(A)$ the eigenvalues, in non-increasing order, counting multiplicities.

For two positive semi-definite matrices $A,B$ with $B\leq A$ (in the sense that $A-B$ is positive semi-definite. so $\langle (A-B)x,x\rangle\geq0$ for all $x$), you have by the [Min-Max Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem)
\begin{align}
\lambda_k(B)&=\min_{\dim M=k}\,\max\{\langle Bx,x\rangle:\ x\in M,\ \|x\|=1\}\\
&\leq \min_{\dim M=k}\,\max\{\langle Ax,x\rangle:\ x\in M,\ \|x\|=1\}\\
&=\lambda_k(A). 
\end{align}
In your case, you have 
$$
V_{t+1}-V_t=A_{t+1}A_{t+1}^T,
$$
which is positive semi-definite.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the proof. I am wondering how to interpret this geometrically. I can think of increasing determinant(thus volume) but can we say anything about direction of Eigen vectors? Or some other geometric notion?